# “json parsing error: Value true at error of type java.lang.Boolean cannot be converted to JSONObject”

Tags: java, android, android-volley

// this is the request method

```
    HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
    params.put("userName",sharedPreferences.getString("name",""));
    params.put("PhoneNumber",sharedPreferences.getString("phone",""));
    params.put("txtMsg",massege.getText().toString());

    JsonObjectRequest req = new JsonObjectRequest(url, new JSONObject(params),
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    try {
                        String code=  response.getString("code");
                        Toast.makeText(getContext(), ""+response.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        if(code.equals("200")){
                            massege.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            send.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            responsemsg.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        }
                        else {

                        }
                        VolleyLog.v("Response:%n %s", response.toString(4));

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            VolleyLog.e("Error: ", error.getMessage());
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), ""+error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(req);[enter image description here][1]
```

get the text from EditText and send to the server using volley. But when I'm executing it, application showing an error:

[image]

What is wrong here???

Comment: `  public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {` seems to be the problem for some reason you get a boolean from the server instead of a JsonResponse

Comment: btw dont you need 2 parameters  for ` VolleyLog.v("Response:%n %s", response.toString(4)); ` after the string ?